# Custom PK-file is not accessible for DVI-driver

Tags: fonts, dvi, metafont

I try to understand how new fonts are created.

1. I drew my stylized letter 'L'.
2. Then I programmed it in Metafont (MyL.mf).

```
    mode_setup;
    fontmaking:=1;
    pixels_per_inch:=600;
    beginchar("L", 10pt#, 10pt#, 0);
      "A stylized letter L";
      z1 = (3/8 w, 7/8 h);
      z2 = (1/8 w, 1/8 h);
      z3 = (5/8 w, 1/8 h);
      z4 = (4/8 w, 2/8 h);
      pickup pencircle scaled 0.15w;
      draw z1--z2--z3--z4;
      penlabels(1, 2, 3, 4);  
    endchar;
    end
```

3. After that I processed MyL.mf with mf.exe (`mf MyL.mf`) and obtained files MyL.2602gf and MyL.tfm.
4. Then I applied gftopk.exe to MyL.2602gf that yielded MyL.2602pk (`gftopk MyL.2602gf MyL.2602pk`).
5. I copied MyL.tfm to the folder with sample.tex.
6. There I wrote

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[russian]{babel}

    \newfont{\letterL}{MyL}
    \newcommand{\otherL}{{\letterL L}}
    \font\myfont=MyL

    \begin{document}
    {\myfont L}
    \otherL
    \end{document}
```

7. I compiled sample.tex with latex.exe. Then I got sample.dvi which I opened with yap.exe.
8. Then I went to C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\public\latex-fonts, created there a folder dpi2602 and placed there MyL.2602pk. I thought a DVI-driver would take PK-files somewhere there...
9. When opening the DVI file, Yap generated an error message saying not all font bitmaps could be created. As a result, both letters L were printed as usual letters L, not my stylized.

I have some questions:

1. Is the sequence of my actions correct in general?
2. Is it enough to run mf.exe and gftopk.exe without any options? I just apply those executables to my files.
3. Where should I put a PK-file so that a DVI-driver such as Yap could take it?
4. All the other PK-files have an extension *.pk but my file is *.2602pk. How to get *.pk file as well?

Comment: Look closely at the output of Step 7 (the `sample.log` file created by running `latex` on `sample.tex`) and at the output of Step 9 (the exact error message generated by the DVI viewer). Does either of them mention anything about fonts being substituted?

Comment: In step 3, try running `mf` with `\mode=ljfour; input MyL` (or something like that).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thank you for your reply. I followed your advice concerning step 3 (```\mode=ljfour; input MyL```). It produced MyL.600gf. Also I changed step 4: ```gftopk MyL.600gf MyL.pk```. Then I placed MyL.pk to the folder with MyL.tfm and sample.tex. Compiled then the tex-file with latex.exe and opened sample.dvi with Yap -- it worked!

Comment: I would try to put the mf source where MiKTeX can find it. Normally it should then be able to create the tfm and the  pk on the fly as it does for other fonts.

Comment: @ close voters: there are four questions in this post but they all ask the same thing (how to apply a font/letter definition) so I think it can stay open (and possibly self-answered or answered by @ShreevatsaR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I succeeded with my own font. Thanks to the answerers.
I have made some changes since the point 3 above.

- I made a batch-file

  ```
  mf.exe "\mode=ljfour; input myL"
  gftopk.exe MyL.600gf myL.pk
  gftodvi myL.600gf
  ```
- Then I copied **both** MyL.tfm and MyL.pk to the folder with .tex file where I use my font. The .tex file is as follows:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[russian]{babel}

  \newfont{\lfont}{myL}

  \begin{document}
  {\lfont L} L
  \end{document}
  ```
- The 1st L is in my font and the 2nd one is in default font (cmr10).
- .tfm file is necessary to LaTeX and the .pk file is for the DVI-driver.